# What does “seien” mean? I can’t find it in the dictionary

Tags: meaning

I came across this phrase in a book I’m reading:

> Seien Sie vorsichtig!

I suspect it’s an odd or outdated way of saying sein.

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/seien https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:sein

Answer (score 2):

This is [imperativ](https://www.google.de/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE768DE768&ei=FyoqWqaoHpLPkgXcq4yAAQ&q=imperative%20deutsch&oq=imperative%20deutsch&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203k1l2j0j0i22i30k1l7.3288.4905.0.5165.8.5.0.3.3.0.344.344.3-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.4.367....0.NPbedjq4Zas) of *sein* when you talk to someone who is older then you or with whom you must talk politely. it is not odd or outdated and means

> Be carefull!

On the other side if you are talking with some friend (e.g. you're using or you can use *du*) it will be used like this:

> Sei doch vorsichtig!

Where *doch* is used to make sentence a little bit milder / not so mandative.

Hope this helps

Comment: Das _doch_ macht den Satz eher strenger beziehungsweise der Sprecher klingt dadurch verärgert. Beispiele: Die Mutter sagt: „_Sei vorsichtig!_“ zum Kind, wenn es nach draußen spielen geht. Sie sagt: „_Sei doch vorsichtig!_“, wenn es beim Abtrocknen eine Tasse fallen lässt.